# How to Get PdfLatex to Display a 2-Page Output on a Single Page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, vertical-alignment, output

The following code (for example)

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 5.25in
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

produces output over two pages:

[image] [image]

I would like to have these two output pages appear as LaTeX output on one page by either displaying page 1  vertically followed by page 2, OR, displayed in a horizontal fashion similar to how I am showing it now by ``cutting and pasting.'' How may I do either of these two things? Thank you.

Comment: there are many tools to post process a pdf to do n-up printing pdfxup, pdfjam, etc

Comment: @David Carlisle If you run my code, you will get 2 pages of output. I want to modify the code in order that both pages are "halfed" so that both appear on only one page. What do I add to the code to do that? Thank you.

Comment: as I say you can run `pdfxup file.pdf` and get a new pdf file with two pages printed on each page.

Comment: @David Carlisle I do not understand what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pgfpages` package as follows

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight 5.25in
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
%\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  I'm sorry that the system will not let me upvote it as I currently have less than 25pts. Incidentally, is there a way that I can specify that the two pages appear vertically on the single page? If not, horizontally is fine  as you have nicely shown.

Comment: Actually, the system did allow me to upvote it. Thanks again for your very helpful answer.

Comment: @Ιδιώτης I think  we can get the two pages to appear one below the other bu it is not as simple for me to do it. I am sorry!

Comment: No problem. Thanks again for your very helpful answer.